# ¿Como se crea un procedimiento almacenado en Oracle?

Tags: plsql

Como podría obtener los datos numéricos de una tabla en especifico para realizar una operación mediante un procedimiento almacenado que devuelva, por ejemplo la división de estos dos datos a otro campo de la misma tabla

Comment: Te explicas como un libro en llamas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Oscar, lo más simple sería esto, tienes una tabla de tres campos (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, DIVISION) y un procedimiento almacenado asociado sería como este:

```
PROCEDURE SP_UPD_MITABLA() IS
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE MITABLA
        SET CAMPO_DIVISION = (CAMPO1/CAMPO2)
        WHERE --ALGUNA LOGICA DE FILTRO
        COMMIT;
    END;
```

Obviamente, tendrías que tener cuidado de que CAMPO2 nunca fuese cero o nulo por ejemplo, para evitar errores.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos nuemricos de una tabla puedes usar el atributo: %type declarada en una variable para que obtenga el mismo tipo de la tabla especifica y en base a eso realizar las operación.

```
declare

valor1 TABLE.campo1%type;
valor2 TABLE.campo2%type;
resultado number;

begin
Select campo1, campo2 into valor1, valor2 from TABLE
where campo1 = unvalor;

resultado=valor1/valor2;

DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('resultado: '||resultado);

end;
```